# Quickest way to calculate $(I-M)^{-1}(I-M^{n+1})$

Tags: matrices

What is the quickest way, as computationally efficient, to calculate $(I-M)^{-1}(I-M^{n+1})$, where $M$ is a given $n \times n$ singular matrix of $0$'s and $1$'s?

My experiments show that the matrix inversion takes an incredible amount of time to complete. Does any matrix decomposition method help at all here? Moreover, what would be the complexity involved?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What happens when you expand and simplify the polynomial product $$(1 - x)(1 + x + \cdots + x^n)?$$ Can you produce a polynomial analogue of the resulting equation?

Comment: I'm failling to see, the expression actually comes from $1 + M + M^2 + \cdots + M^n$, albeit the matrix inversion accounts for the majority of computational efforts.

Comment: Yes, the polynomial analogue is $1-x^{n+1}$. I'm silly enough to not know how to use this. (Entschuldigung!)

Comment: The product is $1 - x^{n + 1}$, which formally looks like $I - M^{n + 1}$, but with $1$ replaced with $I$ and $x$ replaced with $M$.